# What's the cause ClientHandlerException

Tags: java, exception, httpclient

I'm getting the error message below:

> clientHandlerExp: A message body reader for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type text/html; charset=utf-8 was not found

How do I sort out the issue? What and where went wrong in the code?

Comment: Are you using jersey ? You might have missed to add some Json/jersy jars to your classpath.

Comment: _What and where went wrong in the code?_ Which code?